# Passing in a character string in a linked list struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char

I have declared my struct as

```
struct linkedStruct
{
char name;
int size;
enum groupstatus status;
struct linkedStruct* next;
};
```

I am trying to pass a char* name variable(a string of characters) in my code into a single node of this struct.
For example, user enters in Jon, i want my char name to store the character string Jon.

I am having some trouble figuring how to go about this. I tried just simply stating (assuming my node name is temp)

```
temp->name = name;
```

However when I print out the name value when I store it, printf returns nothing.

I originally had it as name[30] in my struct, as we are to assume that the name is less than 30 characters, however this ultimately confused me more because I kept getting errors when trying to store the name into the struct with a for loop.

Other implementation of my struct

```
struct linkedStruct
{
char name[30]; //now a character array
int size;
enum groupstatus status;
struct linkedStruct* next;
};
```

The code was

```
for(int i = 0; i< sizeof(name); i++){
name[i] = temp->name[i];
//seemed totally wrong to do but I had no idea how to go about it

}
```

I was just wondering how I would go about storing it in either situation, as my current code does not work. In my name[30] implementation, I have no idea how to state/access the array notation of the struct.

Comment: forgot to mention, the name variable being passed in is a pointer to char.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. A variable of type `char` has room for exactly one character.

If you know names are limited to 30 characters, you should have

```
char name[30];
```

in the structure declaration. Strings in C are copied using `strcpy()`, so you'd do something like this to set the name inside the structure:

```
struct linkedStruct temp;
strcpy(temp.name, "hello");
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to learn to always use `strncpy` or similar before you write code that's full of buffer overflow hazards. There should be no reason to ever used `strcpy` in general.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
strcpy(temp->name, name);
```

Instead of:

```
temp->name = name;
```

Which copies a string from the pointer `temp->name` to memory at pointer `name`.

## Note

You must ensure that `name` string doesn't contain more than 29 characters.